# Fresh or smoked sausage in Jambalaya?

Tags: sausages, chorizo, cajun-cuisine

Jambalaya calls for either Andouille or Chorizo sausage.

Is this sausage meant to be fresh or smoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do both.  Fresh, you already know.  If it is smoked, sautee in a little oil, then remove.  The oil took on the flavor, so then you can add back the sausage at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh ... needs to take on the flavor of the sausage